# How to create a ramdom number generator that generates 100 numbers from 1-1000 in python

Tags: python

I'm recently just started coding and its been a little bit rough. I was recently given an assignment that's wants me to create a number generator that generates 100 numbers from 1-1000. After that I need to find the average of the smallest and biggest number in the list. I've been having trouble with finding the average so if you can help me it would be great!

My code:

```
import random
for i in range(100):
    y = random.randint(1, 1000)
    print(y)


def mean(values):

        length = len(values)

        total_sum = 0

        for i in range(length):
            total_sum += values[i]
        total_sum = sum(values)

        average = total_sum/length

        return average

x = [y]

n = mean(x)

print (n)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you generate a random value (y) and then throw it away.

Instead you need to keep a list of the generated values,

```
values = []
for i in range(100):
    y = random.randint(1, 1000)
    values.append(y)
```

which could be more compactly written as

```
values = [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(100)]
```

Next, you are duplicating work:

```
    # this finds the sum
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += values[i]

    # this *also* finds the sum (and overwrites your previous result)
    total_sum = sum(values)
```

You can find the smallest and largest values with `min()` and `max()`; then the whole thing becomes

```
values = [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(100)]
smallest = min(values)
largest = max(values)
average = (smallest + largest) / 2
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get your hundred numbers:

```
nums = [random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(100)]
```

Use `1001` as your second argument to `range` if you want to include `1000`.

Next, average the smallest and greatest:

```
avg = (max(nums) + min(nums)) / 2.
```

EDIT: I changed `2` to `2.` in the calculation of the average so  Python will evaluate the expression as a float rather than an int. Otherwise Python would do an integer division, which basically rounds your average down to the nearest int.

Comment: `Otherwise Python would do an integer division` specifically Python2, which OP does not appear to be using.

Comment: Is that the correct average calc or would it be: sum(nums) / len(nums)

Comment: The way I interpreted OP, they're looking for the average of the min and the max ("average of the smallest and biggest number in the list")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: random_nums = [random.randint(1,1000) for _ in xrange(100)]
In [3]: len(random_nums)
Out[3]: 100
In [4]: random_nums_mean = (max(random_nums) + min(random_nums)) / 2
In [5]: random_nums_mean
Out[5]: 500
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Python is easy to write and read.

you can get average just use `max` and `min` (each return max, min from list)

```
from random import randint

# it's generate 100 random number, it's called list comprehension.
random_numbers = [randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(100)]

average = (max(random_numbers) + min(random_numbers)) / 2
```